# Azure eventhub capture replay

Tags: c#, azure-storage, avro, azure-eventhub

**Scenario**

I create an eventhub on Jan 1st 2018.

My eventhub retention period is set to be 1 day.

I enable the "**capture**", leaving the default capture parameters of every 5 mins or 300 mb, feature and store in a container named "**customerevents**"

I send, and process, 1000,000 customer events to my eventhub up to today, 22nd October 2018.

I create a new service for a different department that is interested in historic data & now need to replay **ALL** the 1000,000 messages I have received since 1st Jan 2018.

I have lots and lots of "folders" in my **customerevents** storage container for year/month/day and every 5 mins and in each an **.avro** file containing my captured events.

How do I "replay" all of these events for my new service?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?